# Cannot classList.toggle on HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, html

I made a Sidebar which i need to hide and show with it's class-methods. When calling the method `Sidebar.show()` from console, it removes the element's `sb-hidden`-class, to make it visible.

`this.htmlElement.classList.toggle('sb-hidden', false)`

However, this does not happen when calling the `Sidebar.show()` method from a 'click'-event-handler in the code.

```
clickButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    blogSidebar.show()
  })
```

Why does the sidebar not show when clicking the `clickButton`?

```js
      if (!("path" in Event.prototype))
Object.defineProperty(Event.prototype, "path", {
  get: function() {
    var path = [];
    var currentElem = this.target;
    while (currentElem) {
      path.push(currentElem);
      currentElem = currentElem.parentElement;
    }
    if (path.indexOf(window) === -1 && path.indexOf(document) === -1)
      path.push(document);
    if (path.indexOf(window) === -1)
      path.push(window);
    return path;
  }
});

class Sidebar {
  constructor() {
    this.htmlElement = document.createElement('div')
    this.htmlElement.className = 'sidebar'

    this.contentElement = document.createElement('div')
    this.contentElement.className = 'sb-content'
    addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      var inSidebar = false
      for (var i = 0; i < event.path.length; i++) {
        if(event.path[i] == this.htmlElement){
          inSidebar = true
          break;
        }
      }
      if(!inSidebar){
        this.hide()
      }
    })
    document.body.appendChild(this.htmlElement)
  }

  show(){
    this.htmlElement.classList.toggle('sb-hidden', false)
    console.log(this)
  }

  hide(){
    this.htmlElement.classList.toggle('sb-hidden', true)
  }

  addAction(action, element){
    switch (action) {
      case 'show':
        element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          this.show()
        })
        break;

      case 'hide':
        element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          this.hide()
        })
        break;
      default:

    }
  }
}

var clickButton = document.getElementById('clickbutton')
      const blogSidebar = new Sidebar()
      clickButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        blogSidebar.show()
      })
      addEventListener('load', () => {
        blogSidebar.show()
      })
```

```css
      body{
        background-color: #000;
      }

.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 999999999;
  transition: right 0.3s;
}

.sb-content{

}

.sb-hidden{
  right: -30vw;
}
```

```html
    <button type="button" name="button" id="clickbutton">Show sidebar</button>
```

Comment: Please don't like to external code when you can post it here. External links can break over time and future readers won't understand this question if that happens.

Comment: Why use `toggle()` if you are forcing the class to be removed? Why not just use `classList.remove('sb-hidden')`